# Personalized TOC in Book: add a line before and after the part

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal

I am struggling and I cannot find my way around this problem.

I am using the book structure and I would like to have a nice TOC with the following elements:

- a "Part" that is included between two horizontal lines (above and below) and a little bit centered.
- the "part" does not have to show the number of page to which is referring to
- the word "Table of Contents" should be all in capital letter
- to add a horizontal line at the end of each part (i.e. at the end of appendix of each part).

I am trying to do that but it seems mostly impossible.
Do you have any suggestion on how can I do that?

Comment: have you tried reviewing multiple templates and building a sample?

Comment: I tried, but I cannot find a template that does what I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer and a hint towards a full one.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
```

For the rest try `texdoc book` and then decide how to change the `\part` code to do the other things you want.

LaTeX does not know when a document division ends, it only knows when one starts. In general if you want to signify the end of, say a `\part`, you will manually have to include text along the lines of `end of part`